# where is mysql_config located on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am trying to install `mysqldb` for `python` as per this tutorial and running into the `mysql_config` problem.

http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/web_development/python/installation/how_to_download_and_install_mysqldb_module_for_python_on_linux.php

However I cannot for the life of my locate `mysql_config` where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed with apt-get or dpkg you can find all files related to the install by running

```
dpkg -L python-mysqldb
```

Comment: I finally did later which is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

On both the Ubuntu systems I have to hand it's located at `/usr/bin/mysql_config`.